# Shared build context for docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to build images and instead of using existing images I am using build context and docker file location. Something like this

```
version: '3.4'

services:  
  WebApplication:
    image: webapplication:build
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./WebApplication/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - C:\Abcfolder:C:\Abcfolder
```

My question is if I add another service such as this

```
webApplication2:
    image: webapplication2:build
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./webapplication2/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - C:\Abcfolder:C:\Abcfolder
```

would this context be shared or would it be created again for the second image. I have a directory structure that contains both these applications, so I am not able to figure out the size of the context and if it's being copied twice or just once.
Also I went through the official documentation but couldn't find anything related to this. If anyone could point me to some resources or could help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing shared between two images, they may share layers, but that all will be transparent to you

Comment: @TarunLalwani so would the context be sent for every service in my compose

Comment: Context is used only during the build time. During the build whatever you copy from the context using a `ADD` or `COPY` statement will go into your container image.

Comment: So that means only once ?

Comment: No, because build will be done for each image, so once per service build. Also the next time docker-compose will use the cached images, so build won't happen again

Comment: Okay Ill accept it as an answer if you'll post it. Also a silly doubt  is there any way i can send the context once and it's used by both the images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your case you have two services `WebApplication` and `webApplication2`, docker will build of these services individually and send the context to both of them.

What gets stored inside the container images will depend on the `ADD` and `COPY` statements you have use the Dockerfile of the two services.

You cannot optimize on sending the context only once and you should not worry about it as well, as there will be no impact to you